# Telephone Number Android WebView without tel in HTML doc

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I have a `webView` and it gets the URL dynamically so I can't edit the `HTML` document. My problem is that I want the app to detect phone numbers and provide intent but the HTML document does not contain an anchor tag for telephone numbers so I cannot detect the URL. Is there any way to make the `WebView` identify phone numbers by itself?

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith(MAIL_TO)){

            final String RE_MAIL = "([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(RE_MAIL);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
            while(m.find()) {
                sendEmail(  m.group(1) );
            }
            return true;
        }else if(url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            String appHint = "Choose phone application";
            context. startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, appHint ));
            return true;
        }
        else{
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: post your url of html doc

Comment: https://www.ingrammicro.de/public/imapp/aus/kontakt.php